# Determine Payment Type for PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I am using the PayPal Express Checkout Merchant SOAP API, is there a way to determine which Payment type was chosen by the buyer?

E.g.:

- Credit Cart type: VISA, MC, AMEX
- Masked Credit Card number
- PayPal (I know you can get the PayPal payment type)

I am using the following from the API:

- DoExpressCheckoutPayment
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails
- GetTransactionDetails
- SetExpressCheckout

Merchant API:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#merchant

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

If the buyer paid through Credit card then u will get a receipt id 
Array
(
    [PAYMENTINFO_0_RECEIPTID] => 5116-7421-7291-5321
)

If the buyer paid through paypal then no receipt id  in the response.

Thanks
Az